# Character counter java

Tags: java, string, character

Im trying to create a piece of code that counts the number of times a character is said in a sentence when inputted. The teacher for the assignment gave us an outline of what is should be but it doesnt make sense.

```
int numOfE = 0;    //a counter
for (int index = 0; index < line.length(); index++)
{
    if(//character_at_index == 'e' or == 'E')
        numOfE++;
}
```

Comment: Could you add to your code the `line` declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you're looking for is `charAt`. Here's an example:

```
String text = "foo";
char charAtZero = text.charAt(0);
System.out.println(charAtZero); // Prints f
```

For more information, see the Java documentation on String.charAt.

If you don't want the result as a char data type, but rather as a string, you would use the Character.toString method:

```
String text = "foo";
String letter = Character.toString(text.charAt(0));
System.out.println(letter); // Prints f
```

Answer (score 0):

For coding problems like this, the commented out part (after the //) is typically where you would insert your answer. In this case you will replace

> //character_at_index == 'e' or =='E'

with your clever bit of code logic.
Hint: charAt()

Answer (score 0):

The assignment asks you to write a condition in the if statement that will determine if a character at position index matches the letter e or E.  You have to translate that to code.

To do this, you need to know how to retrieve a character at a given position in a string and how to compare two characters.

Comment: how would i start? i have no idea how to do that

Comment: Because this is an assignment, I can't give you the answer.  I can only point you to what you need to do.  To get a character out a string, use the method String.charAt(index) and to compare if two characters are the same, use the == operator.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8, it can be simply achieved (Stream and Lambda) as follows:

```
String someString = "ExcellencE";
long count = someString.chars().filter(ch -> (ch == 'E' || ch == 'e')).count();
System.out.println(count);
```

Console output:

> 4

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that with a char method it counts every e in a sentence. I had it formatted incorrectly so it counted every letter instead of just e's

```
int countChar;
 char e;
String str;
int count = 0;
System.out.println("input your sentence:");
str = in.nextLine();
str = in.nextLine();

for(i=0; i < str.length(); i++)
{    if(str.charAt(i) == 'e')
        count++;
}

System.out.println("The sentence contains" + ' ' + count + ' ' + "E and e");
```